# Plupload not working with internet explorer 8/9

Tags: json, spring-mvc, internet-explorer-8, plupload

I am using plupload plugin to upload file and Server side I am using Spring MVC. It is working fine with IE 10+ and chrome, firefox but not with IE 8/9. In IE 8/9 I get HTTP error 406.

Below is my Server side code:

```
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="uploadFile")
 public MyJsonResponse uploadPoHardCopy(final HttpServletRequest request){
    MyJsonResponse jsonRespone = new MyJsonResponse();
    //
    //  populate jsonResponse
    //
    return jsonRespone; // return populated jsonResponse
}
```

javascript code:

```
 FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
     var jResponse = info.response;
     var result = $.parseJSON(jResponse);


}
```

To correct the error, I controverted the Object to JSON using Gson and returned it as a String as below:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "uploadFile")
public String uploadPoHardCopy(final HttpServletRequest request){
    MyJsonResponse jsonRespone = new MyJsonResponse();
    //
    //  populate jsonResponse
    //
    return new Gson().toJson(jsonRespone); // return populated jsonResponse
}
```

Now, it is working fine with IE 8/9 but with other browsers I need to parse the response 2 times to get JSON object as below.

```
FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
     var jResponse = info.response;
     var result = $.parseJSON(jResponse);
     result = $.parseJSON(result);

}
```

Could any one please suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fiddler I checked HTTP request/response and observed that IE 8/9 were sending Headers -  **Accept:*/*** . While other browsers were sending  **Accept: application/json** .

So,  I added below option in js code :

```
headers:{Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
```

and reverted the earlier changes that I made for IE 8/9 i.e. change in controller code to return String and in js code to parse response 2 times

Now, it is working fine with all the browsers.